# Creating a GIF with fluent-ffmpeg, overlay is not shown?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a GIF from an mp4 video, with an overlay on it. So there are two inputs, `video.mp4` and `overlay.png`, both of them are https urls.

The gif is created, ffmpeg shows no errors but the overlay doesn't appear in the gif. The code:

```
ffmpeg()
    .withOptions([
        '-i video.mp4'
        `-ss 1`,
        `-i overlay.png`,
        '-f gif',
        `-filter_complex [0:v]trim=duration=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=450:-1[trimmed];[trimmed]split[trimmed1][trimmed2];[trimmed2]reverse[rev];[trimmed1][rev]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v][1:v]overlay=0:0:format=rgb[overlayed];[overlayed]split[a][b];[a]palettegen=stats_mode=diff[palette];[b][palette]paletteuse=bayer:bayer_scale=3.5`
    ])
    .on('start', cmdLine => {
        console.log(`Started FFMpeg`, cmdLine);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(`Success!.`);
        resolve();
    })
    .on('error', (err: Error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(` Error:`, err.message);
        console.error('stdout:', stdout);
        console.error('stderr:', stderr);
        reject();
    })
    .pipe(destinationStream, { end: true });
```

Note: I have to use a stream, instead of saving to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the order of the args. If I order them this way:

```
[
    `-ss 1`,
    '-i video.mp4'    
    `-i overlay.png`,
    `-filter_complex [0:v]trim=duration=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=450:-1[trimmed];[trimmed]split[trimmed1][trimmed2];[trimmed2]reverse[rev];[trimmed1][rev]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v][1:v]overlay=0:0:format=rgb[overlayed];[overlayed]split[a][b];[a]palettegen=stats_mode=diff[palette];[b][palette]paletteuse=bayer:bayer_scale=3.5`
    '-f gif'
]
```

Then the overlay shows up. I didn't know the order mattered for ffmpeg.